# Could not access to my application in digital ocean through public IP?

Tags: digital-ocean, mern, ufw, web-application-firewall

I faced an issue regarding the ufw ubuntu firewall rule in the digital ocean, I already allow the port in from anywhere but still, I can not access my application with public ip with the port that I allowed. How to allow the ufw firewall rule for my application in secure ways. Thank you.

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    134.238.123.131
8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

The problem is, I can not access to my MERN stack application via public IP 134.238.123.131:3000, the thing is, before I abled to access to it. It shows site could not be reached as below:

```
This site can’t be reached
104.248.153.121 took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

[ufw firewall rule status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FuWP.png)

Comment: Apologies if this is a stupid question but, have you configured the Firewall on DigitalOcean to permit TCP traffic to port `3000` on the Droplet? https://cloud.digitalocean.com/networking/firewalls

Comment: One test you can perform is to SSH onto the Droplet and try GETting the endpoint localhost:3000 to prove the service is running on the port. This eliminates the service and focuses attention on networking.

Comment: Yes, I will try it out and thank you for your suggestions.